# JcrPackage getSize() is always 0

Tags: aem, jackrabbit

In my code (AEM 6.1 SP 1) I build packages programmatically. All works fine, except that I want to log the package size - and whatever I tried, it was always 0.
Here's a current code snippet:

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(backupPath + "/" + fileName);
JcrPackageManager packageManager = packaging.getPackageManager(resolver.adaptTo(Session.class));
packageManager.assemble(jcrPackage.getDefinition(), listener, out);
logger.trace("Package size is {}.", jcrPackage.getSize());
```

I tried to close the package and reopen it afterwards, I committed the resource resolver, refreshed the session, but the result was the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the `infinity.json` of your package node once it is created ?

Comment: I can even download the package with all the content inside - a few thousand nodes... So I guess the package is there. Might there be a delay?

Comment: What I was getting at was (as Ameesh said), the `infinity.json` or even `1.json` of your package node would give you the jcr property `:jcr:data` which is essentially used by packmgr UI to display package size.

Comment: e.g this `/etc/packages/Adobe/granite/com.adobe.granite.httpcache.content-1.0.2.zip.1.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error and the hints from Ameesh and Abhishek I found out what the problem was:

```
assemble(JcrPackageDefinition definition, 
         ProgressTrackerListener listener, OutputStream out)
```

does in fact not store the assembled package in the repository. That's why the size is 0. The package is passed to the OutputStream instead - which, in my case, saved the package to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The way getSize works for JcrPackageImpl is that it looks for the "jcr:content" node on the path of the package and tries to get the property "jcr:data" and the length of this property value is returned in the size.
Can you confirm if the path/node you are trying to store the package is "jcr:content" node, My assumption is that its not, thats why you are getting 0 in the package size.

Comment: See my comment on Abisheks question.

Comment: I am not denying that the package is not created, what I am talking about is the logic to get the size in JcrPackageImpl.

Using your IDE if you click on getSize method, you will see logic to get the node "jcr:content", also you will see the implementation only if you have unobfuscated uber jar for aem.